# How to change the value of a check box onClick using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dom-events, ternary-operator

Here I am trying to change the value of the following check box while clicking on it. In the code below I tried to change the value of the checkbox to 1 and change the value to 0 when unchecked. But it takes only the false condition, when the checkbox is unchecked the value changes to 0 but when checked its not changing to 1. Any suggestions how to fix this out ?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="read" name="permission[]" onClick="($(this).checked)?$(this).attr('value',1):$(this).attr('value',0)"/>
```

Comment: Typically you don't want to change the `value` attribute of checkboxes (or radio buttons)... (see posted answer).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*I don't really understand why you would want to do this (the checkbox's value won't be submitted anyways when it's unchecked).*

The [`checked` property on the DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement) will always tell you whether it is checked or not. So you can either get `this.checked` (Javascript DOM) or [`$(this).prop('checked')`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) (jQuery wrapper).

If you really need to, you should do this:

```
onclick="$(this).attr('value', this.checked ? 1 : 0)"
```

or even

```
onclick="$(this).val(this.checked ? 1 : 0)"
```

or even better, [don't use inline event handlers](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html#link2) (like `onclick`), but use jQuery's event handling wrappers ([`.on('click')`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) in older versions).

[jsFiddle Demo with jQuery event handling](http://jsfiddle.net/JySSN/)

---

#### The problem with your approach

You are using `$(this).checked` to get the state of your checkbox. The jQuery object (the one that's returned by the `$` function) does not have a `checked` property, so it will be `undefined`. In Javascript, `undefined` is a *falsy* value, that's why your checkbox's value is always `0`.

Comment: thank you for the best answer that saved  me from wasting another day with searching

Answer (score 1):

```js
// o = object
function get(o) { 

  ( $(o).val() == 0 ) ? $(o).val(1) : $(o).val(0);
    
  // alert( $(o).val() );
    
  console.log( $(o).val() );
  
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="permission[]" onClick="get(this)" value="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple click function to achieve it.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="read" name="permission[]" value="0"/>
```

**Jquery:**

```js
$("#read").click(function() {

  if($("#read").val()==0)
  {
   $("#read").val(1);
  }
  else
  {
   $("#read").val(0);
  }
  alert($("#read").val());
  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="read" name="permission[]" value="0"/> 
Click the check box to toggle the value 0 and 1
```