# Make html checkbox send true / false in serialization

Tags: javascript, html, spring

I have the following checkbox in a form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="preparationNeeded" >
```

This is sent to a SpringController via javascript:

```
.ajax({
                        type : 'POST',
                        url : '${home}ui' + action + name + '.html',
                        data : $('#updateform').serialize(),
                        success : function(data) {
                            console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
                            document.getElementById('viewmodal').style.display = 'none';
                            display(data);
                        },
                        error : function(e) {
                            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
                            displayError(e.responseText);
                        }
                    });
```

The serialization is the following:

**When checked:**

```
FORM:  id=1& ... preparationNeeded=true ...
```

**When unchecked(checkbox value not included):**

```
FORM:  id=1& ...
```

This is parsed to an object with the boolean field **Article.preparationNeded**. This works fine in almost all cases but the problem is that **preparationNeded** has the default value of **true.**

So, if the checkbox is checked, the value true is sent correctly. But if the checkbox is not checked, the value is not serialized and is taking the default value of the field, instead of **false**.

Some suggestions:

[How to change the value of a check box onClick using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140633/how-to-change-the-value-of-a-check-box-onclick-using-jquery)

> you can also consider introducing a hidden input

The problem if I include a Hidden value with **value="false"** this works fine when the checkbox is not checked. But if this is checked the serialization is the following:

```
FORM:  id=1& ... preparationNeeded=false&preparationNeeded=true ...
```

This raise an org.springframework.validation.FieldError

```
Field error in object 'item' on field 'preparationNeeded': rejected value [false,true]; codes [typeMismatch.item.preparationNeeded,typeMismatch.preparationNeeded,typeMismatch.boolean,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [item.preparationNeeded,preparationNeeded]; arguments []; default message [preparationNeeded]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String[]] to required type [boolean] for property 'preparationNeeded'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [false,true]]
```

Bacause the value is **"false,true"**

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default of the checkbox to be false so that when the form is parsed into an object, it will only be true if the checkbox was checked.

If you want it to be checked by default so that the user doesn't have to click it, you can check the box manually via JavaScript when the page loads.

Comment: heheh, yes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could change the checkbox to a dummy name, and make preparationNeeded a hidden field, and use JS to set the value of preparationNeeded appropriately on every change to the checkbox state.

Comment: If you wanted to as well, you could specify an attribute on the dummy checkbox so that you can use $('#updateForm :input[name!="preparationNeededDummy"]').serialize() to keep it out of the serialized form data you submit.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to observe clicks on the checkbox and when the checkbox is checked, clear the name on the hidden input. That way the hidden input value will only be added to the serialized output when the checkbox is not checked.

See a demonstration of this below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#serialize').click(serializeForm);
  $('#preparationNeededCheckbox').click(handleCheckboxClick);
});

function serializeForm() {
  console.log('serialized form: ',$('#updateform').serialize());
}

function handleCheckboxClick() {
  $('#hiddenCheckboxInput').attr('name', this.checked ? '' : this.name);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="updateform">
  Needs Preparation: <input type="checkbox" name="preparationNeeded" value="true" id="preparationNeededCheckbox" />
  <input type="hidden" name="preparationNeeded" value="false" id="hiddenCheckboxInput" />
</form>
<button id="serialize">Serialize</button>
```

But perhaps it might be simpler to have two radio buttons- one for true, one for false...