# Checkbox not replacing true with false using AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an application where a user would check off an input checkbox and that value would be sent to the database without reloading the page; which it does. However, when I uncheck that same element its hidden type; which contains a value of 0, is not submitted, instead, it still submits the value of 1 from the checkbox.

Inputs are created dynamically:

```
function build_something(it, src){


  var something = it;
  var htag = it+"-header";


  var ctr = document.createElement('div');
  ctr.setAttribute('class', 'interest_container');

  var lbl = document.createElement('label');
  lbl.setAttribute('for', something);

  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.setAttribute('src', src);

  var title = document.createElement('h2');
  title.setAttribute('id', htag);

  var inp_f =document.createElement('input');
  inp_f.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  inp_f.setAttribute('name', something);
  inp_f.setAttribute('value', 0);

  var inp = document.createElement('input');
  inp.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  inp.setAttribute('id', something);
  inp.setAttribute('name', something);
  inp.setAttribute('value', 1);


  lbl.appendChild(img);
  ctr.appendChild(lbl);
  ctr.appendChild(inp_f);
  ctr.appendChild(inp);
  ctr.appendChild(title);

  var elem = document.getElementById('idk');
  elem.appendChild(ctr);

  document.getElementById(htag).innerHTML = it;
}
```

Binds nearest element grabs input and `onchange` post checked element:

```
$('#interests').on('change', 'input', function (e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:  'some.php',
    async:  true,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success:  function (msg) {
      console.log(msg);

    }
  });
})
```

storeData is a function called by `some.php`:

```
function storeData($form_data, $table_name, $cxn){
  if(!is_array($form_data)){
    return false;
    exit();
  }
  $types = str_repeat("s", count($form_data));
  $params = array();
  $params[] = &$types;
  $keys = array_keys($form_data);
  $values = array_values($form_data);
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
    $params[] = &$values[$i];
  }

  $sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name (" . implode(',', $keys) . ") VALUES (" .
  implode(',', array_fill(0, count($values), '?')) . ")
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ";
  $updates = implode(',', array_map(function($col) {
    return "$col = VALUES($col)";
  }, $keys));
  $sql .= $updates;

  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($cxn, $sql);
  call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);
  return mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

when I check the input box it submits the value and stores it; however, when I uncheck that same element it should send a value 0 but it doesn't.

EDIT: my issue is different because the other solution suggestion a dropdown. I do not want that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery serialize does not register checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029870/jquery-serialize-does-not-register-checkboxes)

Comment: Perhaps the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44314075/1575353) will be found interesting

Answer (score -1):

because if uncheck checkbox not this not send request value to server.In PHP use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check value availble.

Comment: you are correct so when i uncheck the box no value is sent at all except for the username. I need to take $(this) element and post it with a value of 0

Comment: check value of checkbox with isset in PHP.