# checkbox onclick wont change checked via jscript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have 3 checkboxes, i wish to be able to click the box and it tick on/off and via jscript change the value of the input for posting to state weather item is accepted or not on another page. However i have logical script but it wont work, theres no errors but the checkboxes wont click on/off they just click on and thats it.. and the value wont change either i dont understand why.

Could somebody look at this short code and tell me why.

Thank you.

```
<input  type="checkbox" id="paypal" name="paypal1"  value=" " onclick='chbxpp();' >
</input>
<label for="paypal" class="checkboxes" >Show PayPal Accepted</label>

<br>

<input   type="checkbox" id="facebook"  name="facebook"  value=" "  onclick='chbxfb(this);' >
</input>
<label for="facebook" class="checkboxes"  >Show FaceBook Contact Details</label>

<br>

<input   type="checkbox" id="twitter"  name="twitter"  value=" "  onclick='chbxtw(this);' >
</input>
<label for="twitter" class="checkboxes"  >Show Twitter Contact Details</label>



function chbxpp()
{

if(document.getElementById('paypal').checked === true) {
document.getElementById('paypal').checked = false;
document.getElementById('paypal').value='no';

var vv=document.getElementById('paypal').value;
console.log(vv);
}

if (document.getElementById('paypal').checked === false) {
document.getElementById('paypal').checked = true;
document.getElementById('paypal').value='yes';
var vv=document.getElementById('paypal').value;
console.log(vv);
}

}




function chbxfb(objfb)
{
var that = objfb;

(objfb);

if(document.getElementById(that.id).checked === true) {
document.getElementById(that.id).checked = false;
document.getElementById(that.id).value='no';

var vv=document.getElementById(that.id).value;

console.log(vv);

}

if (document.getElementById(that.id).checked === false) {
document.getElementById(that.id).checked = true;
document.getElementById(that.id).value='yes';

var vv=document.getElementById(that.id).value;

console.log(vv);

}

}



function chbxtw(objtw)
{
var that = objtw;
(objtw);


if(document.getElementById(that.id).checked === true) {
document.getElementById(that.id).checked = false;
document.getElementById(that.id).value='no';
var vv=document.getElementById(that.id).value;
console.log(vv);
}

if (document.getElementById(that.id).checked === false) {
document.getElementById(that.id).checked = true;

document.getElementById(that.id).value='yes';

var vv=document.getElementById(that.id).value;

console.log(vv);

}

}
```

The objpp was my attempt at another method but just does the same thing...

p.s if i just didnt use jscript and just had the html, would the value not be valid if the checkbox was not clicked or would the value still be sent...

iv just fond this..

[How to change the value of a check box onClick using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140633/how-to-change-the-value-of-a-check-box-onclick-using-jquery)

states that the value wont be sent if the box is unchecked... But then how do i know after post what has been clicked.... will i receieve a not isset($_POST['paypal'])   or an empty($_POST['paypal'])

Comment: Are you really using jscript or JavaScript?

Comment: i thought they where both the same, seems to be the norm.

Comment: They're not. Read the tag descriptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to Ryan Wilson's answer, set your cbx's initial value to false. (Also check the format of the cbx - the closing tag.)

```
<input  type="checkbox" id="paypal" name="paypal1"  value="false" onchange="chbxpp();" />

function chbxpp() {

    // the cbx starts false. when it is clicked for the first time it
    // becomes true.

    if (document.getElementById('paypal').checked) {
        // you don't need this.
        //document.getElementById('paypal').checked = true;
        document.getElementById('paypal').value = 'yes';

        var vv = document.getElementById('paypal').value;
        console.log(vv);
    } else {
        // you also don't need this.
        //document.getElementById('paypal').checked = false;
        document.getElementById('paypal').value = 'no';
        var vv = document.getElementById('paypal').value;
        console.log(vv);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I imagine your checkboxes begin with no check inside them or .checked === false, but when you call your function chbxpp(), it looks to see if your .checked property === true and if so it sets it back to false. The click event already changes the checkbox's .checked property for you, no need to do it in your code.

```
//If the checkbox is checked, set it to not checked...??? 
//But the problem is, the click event just set the .checked property to true
//so setting it back to false makes it like it never happened.
if(document.getElementById('paypal').checked === true) {
   //document.getElementById('paypal').checked = false; //This part is a no-no
   document.getElementById('paypal').value='yes';

}else{
   document.getElementById('paypal').value='no';
}
```

Comment: I am sooo stupid for not realising that, you made it so logically simple, thank you.

Comment: @MelissaHicking No problem. Glad I could help. Have a good day! :)

Comment: I have also formatted all 3 scripts into the 1. Thank you very much guys.